# Help explain a simple-random walk problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading some material about simple random walk (each time either goes up or goes down with equal probability $1/2$) as the following, I don't understand what does the highlighted sentence mean.

[image]

Here ${\bf x} = {\bf x}(0),{\bf x}(1),...,{\bf x}(n),...$ represents the random walk. What does it mean by "**$R$ "identical in law to" 1 + a copy of $T$**? I don't think it means $R = 1 + T$ because if the ${\bf x}(1) = -1$, then we must have $R < T$.

Comment: The wording is crystal clear and the sentence means that the random variables $R$ and $1+T$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the wording is pretty confusing there, but what I think he means is that (due to the Markov property), there is no real difference between starting a walk $W_1$ from a point $p$ at time $t$ and another walk $W_2$ reaching $p$ at time $t$ and continuing, and any quantities based on this are similarly identical.

Here in particular, due to the problem definition, the probability laws of $T$ and $R$ are offsets of each other based on the starting point. 
That is, $\mathbb{P}_1(T)$ is the same as $\mathbb{P}_0(R)$, assuming that subscript meant starting point :/

Also, I think he says a "copy" of $T$, because we may have reached 1 before, and thus need to "reset" $T$ for it to make sense.